# How to set the activity name as a variable in os_activity_initiate?

Tags: ios, ios8, activity-tracing

Here when I tried setting the "test_activity" string as a variable I am getting some errors.

```
os_activity_initiate("test_activity", OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DEFAULT, ^(void) {

});
```

How to set the activity name as a variable here? something like given below.

```
os_activity_initiate(activity_name, OS_ACTIVITY_FLAG_DEFAULT, ^(void) {

});
```

I could see the following function "_os_activity_initiate", but it is mentioned that "Do not use directly because your description will not be preserved" not sure what does it means? Any idea? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible - `os_activity_initiate()` requires the first argument to be a static string. You cannot use a variable here.